# How to limit the SecurityInfo. to appear only once per root domain per URL hit

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using webExtension SecurityInfo API. For example, I want to see if HSTS is enabled. I only want to know this info. once per tab. For example, in this code, I want to check if HSTS is enabled.

`background.js`:

```
sync function logger(details) {
  try {
    let securityInfo = await browser.webRequest.getSecurityInfo(
      details.requestId, {}
    );
    console.log("URL",details.url)

    if ((securityInfo.state == "secure" || securityInfo.state == "weak") &&
        !securityInfo.isUntrusted) {
        console.log("HSTS:",securityInfo.hsts)
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(logger,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

when I open `google.com` I receive dozens of responses in the `browser console` for many links that are for `google.com` or for embedded links in the same page.

I am only interested to know the SecurityInfo. for the root domain of the URL I hit the URL bar. Nothing else. For example, if I hit `mail.google.com` I want to know the HSTS status for `google.com`. If I again enter a new address in the same tab, say, `yahoo.com`, I am interested in knowing the SecurityInfo for `yahoo.com`.

If I open a new tab for `google.com` I want this info to appear again as it is a new tab, despite the fact that I saw it in previous tab.

I.e. I am only interested in knowing the SecurityInfo of the root domain (not subdomains) once per URL hit.

And, the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Example",
  "description": "Example.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "icons/icon-32.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Example",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  },
  "icons": {
    "32": "icons/icon-32.png"
  },
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "62.0b5"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the second argument of `browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener` from `{urls: ["<all_urls>"]}` to `{url: ["<all_urls>"], types: ["main_frame"]}`.
This means you will only get an event for the top-level "frame" load without all the resources on the page.

> Top-level documents loaded into a tab.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/ResourceType

Comment: How to receive the header only once? for the root domain? because I receive many headers due to redirections for example? any suggestions?

Comment: I think you could filter at least HTTP redirects with `details.statusCode >= 300 && details.statusCode < 400`.